# Bought first mac ever (mac mini), but stuck on install

Tags: install, mac-mini

I just bought my first ever mac - mac mini - and now I'm trying to get it running. I have connected it to a dell monitor through hdmi and a windows usb keyboard so far.

When I power it on I get the screen with the apple and a progress bar. Once this progress bar is done, the screen turns sort of dark gray for like 10 seconds and then 2 images are displayed (one at a time). They both seem to indicate that I need to turn on/off some switch but there are no switches on my mac mini it seems?! I have network cable plugged in in case that is any help. Check out the images here:

[image: First image]

And the second image:
[image: second image]

Comment: You need to connect a mouse and a keyboard at this stage.

Comment: What model Mac Mini do you have? New or used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second image, at least, clearly indicates that your computer wants you to turn on the mouse. You need to have a mouse either plugged in through USB, or available to pair via Bluetooth. You say you already have a keyboard plugged in, so that should be okay.

Comment: Thanks for the swift input!

I tried connecting both mouse and keyboard now, but it actually seems that none of them are actually "registered".. Any ideas why this might be? (both of them work on my windows pc).

Comment: AFAIK, pretty much any USB keyboard and mouse should work with a Mac Mini.  Are you sure they are not trying to connect by bluetooth?

Comment: You're awesome, it is working now! Huge thanks (y)

Comment: PNS, So what did you do differently?

Comment: I tried removing the usb from both mouse and keyboard, turning them off, adding them again and then turn them on. Seemed to do the trick.